# аналог XSLT для JSON

Tags: json, xslt

Друзья... всегда использовали XML для передачи данных. Если нужен был адаптер между системами, то в нем делали преобразование путем XSLT, что было очень удобно и здорово. Берешь одну схему, берешь другую схему. Указываешь что из какого атрибута в какой идет, ге какие преобразования и все супер...

И вот в рамках микросервисной архитектуры мы перешли на формат JSON.  В JSON также возможна генерация по схеме, как и в XML, но... я нигде не могу найти аналога XSLT. Не может быть, чтобы его не было...  Адаптеры приходится писать например на JAVA,  что существенно замедляет разработку...

Собственно об этом и вопрос - есть ли для JSON аналог XSLT

Comment: [JSON Awesome](https://github.com/burningtree/awesome-json)
[JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/)

Comment: Так это схемы, это аналог XSD. А мне нужен xslt. е туда смотрю?

Comment: Я просто не понял изначальную цель. Как видите, для JSON есть много всего. Но какую именно вы задачу решаете? Что для вас делает XSLT? Или нужен просто генератор кода?

Comment: Ок. Объясняю. Мы имеем платформу миросервисов. Микросервисы взаимодействуют друг с другом посредством обмена JSON. И вот беда... каждый микросервис использует свою модель данных.Ну что сделать- Agile. Ок..начали использовать JSONschema, как вы правильно указали. Но преобразование между схемами все равно используем написанные на JAVA. Вот и возник вопрос, а есть ли для JSON свой механизм трансформации из схемы в схему, как это ест у XML/

Comment: речь идет об иcпользвании механизма трансформации в адаптере между микросервисами. Вот не кайф писать его на JAVA, Хорошо бы использовать что-то типа XSLT.

Comment: Ну так вы же понимаете, что за трансформации отвечает код написанный на Java, но не сами шаблоны в XSLT. Вот там целый раздел есть [по трансформациям](https://github.com/burningtree/awesome-json#transformations) (правда почти везде JavaScript) и есть еще [8 библиотек на Java](https://github.com/burningtree/awesome-json#libraries).

Comment: Конечно, но шаблон сущесмтвенно ускоряет дело. И шаблон делает аналитик, а не разработчик. С шаблоном дело пошло бы веселее.

Comment: Согласен с вами, конечно, JSON не для Java. В JS все трансформации делаются на нативном языке коротко и в стиле монад. В Java конечно на все вещи уходят мегабайты исходного кода. Чего стоят одни проверки на исключения...

Comment: я вот смотрю на JSONT. https://goessner.net/articles/jsont/ Вот мне кажется это то, что я ищу...

Answer (score 0):

Итак... JSON или XML? Это вечный спор. Считается, что XML хорош для сервеной части, а JSON для клиентской. Считалось так, во всяком случае. Говорили, что JSON невозможно привязать к схеме... но тут бац.. и схема есть - JSONschema. Если её прикрутить к сервису, то можно генерировать сообщения по схеме. Чем не аналог XSD для XML?
И вот задались мы вопросом, а хорошо бы получить механизм типа XSLT для JSON. Было бы здорово. Почему? да потому что аналитик делает эту схему преобразований сам, отдает разработчику, которому в данном случае не надо думать и вносить свои ошибки, и он её прикручивает к сервису. И вот, я такой аналог нашел https://goessner.net/articles/jsont/.

Comment: Сегодняшняя схема JSON соответствует стандарту XSD 1.0, выпущенному в 2001 году. Стандарт XSD 1.1 был выпущен в 2012 году. JSON не имел ничего аналогичного.

Comment: Есть предложение добавить обработку JSON в XSLT: https://www.saxonica.com/qt4specs/XT/Overview-diff.html

Comment: что значит "предложение"? этой фишки стоит ждать или она уже есть?

Comment: Эта версия XSLT 4.0 еще не выпущена.

Comment: "Сегодняшняя схема JSON соответствует стандарту XSD 1.0, выпущенному в 2001 году. Стандарт XSD 1.1 был выпущен в 2012 году. JSON не имел ничего аналогичного"   В смысле не имел ничего аналогичного? сейчас  по JSONschema можно генерировать сообщения? что вы имеете ввиду, что JSON отстает от XML на 12 лет?

Comment: В целом, существует процесс копирования стека технологий XML в JSON. XML XSD 1.0 и схема JSON очень примитивны. XSD 1.1 был большим достижением в функциональности.

Comment: http://www.xfront.com/xml-schema-1-1/xml-schema-1-1-for-managers.ppt?v=15